# What is byte(Java) equivalent in dart?

Tags: dart, variables

I want to use **byte** variable to store byte data, but can't find *anything yet.*
I know about byte array equivalent is Unit8List.

Comment: Sorry, dart no have equivalent.

Comment: can we use var/dynamic in place of byte @DaniloMercadoOudalova

Comment: But is nota equivalent

Comment: You can use an `int` to store a byte value.  The range of `int` is larger than that of an 8-bit byte, but unless you care about memory layout (in which case you should be using `Uint8List`), that usually shouldn't matter.

Comment: I am very concise with bits cause i am manipulating bits via << or >> in password generation. @jamesdlin I can't use Uint8List cause its byte[](JAVA). I was asking for byte(JAVA) equivalent

Comment: You can do bit manipulation on an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Dart has only one integer type, `int`.
Those values are either signed 64-bit integers on the native VM, or non-fractional doubles when compiled to JavaScript (and then bit-wise operators only work on 32 bits, like in JavaScript).

So, if you want to store an integer, even a byte sized one, use `int`.

If you want to ensure that your results are constrained to 8 bits, you can use `result = result.toUnsigned(8);` afterwards (or just `result &= 0xff;`).